# How to use Google Chart DateRangeFilter ui.step

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a Google Charts line chart with a date range filter working, but when I move the slider, it changes the range by one day at a time.  I would like it to change by one month at a time instead.  I thought I could use the ui.step option for this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I construct my data in a loop like this, and pass it to [google.visualization.arrayToDataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable):

```
chartData[i] = [
  new Date(year, month, day),  
  value
];
```

Then I have a `DateRangeFilter` that looks like this:

```
var dateRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'DateRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'chartFilter',
                    'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'Date',
                        'ui': {'label': 'Date Range'}
                }
            })
```

I create a `LineChart` and `Dashboard` with the date range filter and the line chart.  The code above works, but if it add the ui.step option, it fails:

```
'ui': {'label': 'Date Range', 'step': 'month'}
```

Errors:

```
One or more participants failed to draw()

Invalid number for increment "month".
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug.  I filed a bug report on it [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1568); you can "star" the issue to get updates on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

"month" value for step is invalid as written in [google-visualization documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls):

> ui.step: The minimum possible change when dragging the slider thumbs: can be any time unit up to "day". ("month" and "year" aren't yet supported.)